# How dependency injection works in C?

Tags: function, pointers, dependencies, code-injection

I'm currently reading "making embedded systems" and I didn't understand dependency injection. I searched but I don't get the logic. What is the real importance of it and where it has to be used exactly in C ? Do I have to use it with function pointer?